# Proving orthogonality of factored polynomials

Tags: integration, polynomials, orthogonality

if $\pi_{n}=(x-x_{1})...(x-x_{n})$ with $x_{i} \neq x_{j}$ for $i\neq j$, and $x_{i} \in [a,b]$ $a,b$ are reals how Can I prove that $\{\pi_{n}\}$ is a sequence of orthogonal polynomials by the following inner product:

$(\pi_{n},\pi_{m})=\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b} \pi_{n} \pi_{m} dx$.

Okay, I just have to prove that $(\pi_{n},\pi_{m})=0$ if $n\neq m$, but i have no idea on how solve this integral.

Comment: What are the bounds of the integral?

Comment: I edited, but it is any real interval that contains the polynomial`s zeros

Comment: Seems untrue then. $x$ and $x(x-1)$ are not orthogonal on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is not true: take $$\pi_1(x)=x-\frac{1}{3}$$ and $$\pi_2(x)=\left(x-\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)$$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$, then $$(\pi_1,\pi_2)=\int_0^1\left(x-\frac{1}{3}\right)^2\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)dx=\frac{1}{36}\neq0,$$ as can be confirmed [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20(x-1%2F3)%5E2(x-1%2F2)%20from%200%20to%201)

Therefore, these polynomials are not orthogonal with respect to the given inner product